# How to properly convert ISO date to MM/DD/YYYY

Tags: javascript

I have a date coming back in this format `2021-12-03T00:00:00.000Z` which I then convert to an ISO date string and then construct a `new Date()` based on the split ISO string. The issue is that my date properly gets formatted with every month except December. Anytime I pass a December date, the logic always converts it to be January of the next year.

Code

```
//bill.date_paid at this point = '2021-12-03T00:00:00.000Z'

let isoDateString = new Date(bill.date_paid).toISOString().split('T')[0].split('-');

//isoDateString = ['2021', '12', '03'];

bill.date_paid = new Date(isoDateString[0], isoDateString[1], isoDateString[2]).getTime();

//date conversion above = 1641193200000 which is equal to a January date...
```

But why?

Comment: Why is `isoDateString` an array with the individual date components and not an ISO-8601 formatted string!

Comment: `isoDateString[1]` is a 1-indexed month (as a string). `Date(year, month, day)` takes a zero-indexed month (as a number).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To convert your iso date to the mm/dd/yyyy format you can use a [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) object like below :

```js
const date = new Date('2021-12-03T00:00:00.000Z');
const result = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(date);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```js
date = new Date('2021-12-03T00:00:00.000Z');    
console.log((date.getMonth()+1)+'/'+(date.getDate()) + '/'+date.getFullYear());
```

Also you can use [moment.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment)

```js
console.log(moment(new Date('2021-12-03T00:00:00.000Z')).format("MM/DD/YYYY"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't convert it directly to time?

```js
let date_paid = '2021-12-03T00:00:00.000Z'
let date = new Date(date_paid).getTime()
console.log(date)
```